# Read a sound backward with DirectSound

Tags: c#, audio

Is it possible to read a sound backward with the managed version of DirectSound?
If not is there another library allowing to make it easily?

Comment: try opening the file as a stream, get the header info, create a new tempfile with the header info and write the stream from the end. open the tempfile as a new directsound object and try to play it

Comment: That is the solution I'm currently trying to implement. I was wondering if there wasn't an easier way.
By the way why didn't you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the WaveFileReader and WaveFileWriter classes from [NAudio](http://www.codeplex.com/naudio) to reverse a WAV file. You need to make sure you use the BlockAlign property of the WaveFormat to read all the bytes for a single sample (4 for stereo 16 bit audio).

```
    public static void ReverseWaveFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(inputFile))
        {
            int blockAlign = reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
            using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(outputFile, reader.WaveFormat))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[blockAlign];
                long samples = reader.Length / blockAlign;
                for (long sample = samples - 1; sample >= 0; sample--)
                {
                    reader.Position = sample * blockAlign;
                    reader.Read(buffer, 0, blockAlign);
                    writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, blockAlign);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Accepted, but I implemented it with DirectSound.