# Reversing a .mp3 programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, mp3

I want to create a simple web service for use within my company that would allow someone to upload a .mp3 file, producing the reversed .mp3 available for them to download ?

How could I write a method using C# to accomplish this task ? Are there any available APIs to do this ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Decode to wav, reverse the sample array, encode as mp3.

Comment: @Esailija or perform a lossless algorithm on the MP3 file format contents! (Don't know if possible, but might be (just like lossless volume changes)).

Comment: FYI there's an answer here on how to do it with NAudio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1221756/1517578. This is just the "reversing a WAV" part.

Comment: @usr probably not because the frames in the mp3 are basically "referencing" other frames because of [bit reservoir](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Bit_reservoir) so you can't just reverse the frames. The volume changes are possible because there is explicit bits for global gain in the encoded form.

Comment: @usr Each frame encodes a block of audio data, so reversing the frame sequence - even if you could - would give you a garbled output.